# Expo WebBrowser not working post production after eas build

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-native, expo

In my React native expo bare project, The Expo WebBrowser works fine in development build using command.
Expo WebBrowser is used to for server side oauth2.0 authentication and redirect using deep linking.

```
"android": "expo run:android"
```

but running and creating a eas build of my project to create an apk the Expo WebBrowser doesn't work

```
"build": "eas build -p android --profile production"
```

Here is package.json

```
{
  "name": "android",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "build": "eas build -p android --profile production",
    "local": "eas build --platform android --local",
    "prod": "npx expo start --no-dev --minify"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/react-native-action-sheet": "^4.0.1",
    "@flyerhq/react-native-chat-ui": "^1.4.3",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.21.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "11.1.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.33",
    "expo": "~50.0.13",
    "expo-auth-session": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-constants": "~15.4.5",
    "expo-crypto": "~12.8.1",
    "expo-document-picker": "~11.10.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.10.3",
    "expo-linking": "~6.2.2",
    "expo-media-library": "~15.9.1",
    "expo-random": "~13.6.0",
    "expo-router": "~3.4.8",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.26.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.9.3",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.8.2",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "npm": "^10.5.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-dialog": "^9.3.0",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^9.1.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-mmkv": "^2.12.2",
    "react-native-offline": "^6.0.2",
    "react-native-really-awesome-button": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-text-input-interactive": "^0.1.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-native-webview": "13.6.4",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "^1.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.3",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "^0.75.0-main"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

here is my expo app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Android",
    "slug": "Android",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "scheme": "com.roxylius.fileshare",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.roxylius.fileShare"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": ["expo-router", "expo-font"],
    "extra": {
      "router": {
        "origin": false
      },
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "30ce18c6-3beb-420c-b065-0d9c59ba4688"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

here is my eas.json that used for eas build

```
{
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "preview4": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "env": {
        "EXPO_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL": "https://shareit-server.azurewebsites.net"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem arises in post-production but the major problem is that is there are no error caused so I am unable to find the bug. Also The can't run in production mode as i use mmkv package with can't be used in expo go for production mode.

here is link to react native repo on [github](https://github.com/roxylius/shareFiles)

To recreate this problem

- Clone my github repo
- `cd Android`
- then install all node_modules using `npx expo install`
- Run the application using `npm run android`
- To build using eas remove `"eas": { "projectId": "30ce18c6-3beb-420c-b065-0d9c59ba4688" }`
- Then run `npm run build` to build using production profile

I tried using `"plugins":[[expo-web-browser]]` in profile `"production"` in eas.json but it doesn't work there is no such thing as plugins in eas profiles it throws an error like this

```
eas.json is not valid. 
- "build.production.plugins" is not allowed
```

other than that, I tried using react-native-webview but It doesn't work with oauth2.0 as it not secure at all.
I am unable to pin point the error causing this.